# Applications of Bernoulli's where there is non-streamline flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am seeing in some academic references that Bernoulli's theorem was applied in venturimeter, bunsen burner, aerofoil lift, carburetor in bikes, sprayer, etc,.. But Bernoulli's equation and theorem was derived based on the assumption that flow of the fluid is streamlined. But I doubt the example applications of this theorem don't have streamline flow and instead it can be turbulent. Do the Bernoulli's theorem can be approximated to non streamlined flow of fluids?